# How to Copy Swap Chain Image to a VkBuffer in Vulkan?

Tags: buffer, vulkan

I am currently modifying the Adreno SDK Vulkan example of Triangle. I want read the color values of the rendered Swap Chain image. The process I followed is as follows:

1. I create VkBuffer with width and height of Swap Chain image.
   Its details:

   ```
   VkBufferCreateInfo outputinfo = {};
   outputinfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
   outputinfo.size = m_width * m_height * 3 * sizeof(int8_t);
   outputinfo.usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT;
   outputinfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;`
   ```

   Int because the Image format is `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_SINT`
   Then allocate memory and bind it to the buffer with type `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT`
2. Call `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer` in Command Buffer after the `vkCmdDraw`, `vkCmdEndRenderPass`.
3. Then do `vkQueueSubmit` and `vkQueueWaitIdle`.
   Call `vkMapMemory` for the Buffer memory and read the data, but they are garbage values. For `malloc` I am keeping the data format as int.

Comment: "*Int because the Image format is VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_SINT*" Two problems. First, I would be shocked if a swap chain image used a 24-bit color format. Especially a non-normalized format. And *signed* on top of that. Second, even if that's really the image format, `SINT` means that it's signed integer. The `8`s tell you how many bits are used per channel. It's 24-bit per pixel, not `3 * sizeof(int)` per pixel. I want to see the code where you query this image format. Also, did you check to see if you could use the image as the source for a transfer operation?

Comment: @NicolBolas I changed the int to int8_t. Secondly since its a Swap chain image so I don't know where to set its usage to trasfer type. We can set usage through VkImageCreateInfo, but don't know for swap chain image.

Comment: @abhijitjagdale: You set the usage flag in the VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR structure that is passed to vkCreateSwapchainKHR. So in addition to VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT you'll have to set the VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT before creating the swap chain if you want to read from it and if that's supported (see Nicol's answer). Also note that Vulkan does not do any image format conversions for you, so you should match the actual swap chains format before copying from it.

Comment: @SaschaWillems 
Setting swapchainCreateInfo.imageUsage  = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT

worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swapchain images in Vulkan do not belong to your code; they belong to the platform. As such, you cannot control most aspects of them. You instead *query* aspects of them, via `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR`. Of particular importance is `VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::supportedUsageFlags`.

These are the image usage flags which the swap chain images support. They're required to support color attachment, but that is the *only* usage for which support is required. This includes using the image as the source of a transfer operation.

If `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT` is not set in that flag, then you cannot copy from a swap chain image *at all*. So you'll have to render what you needed to a different image, then copy to the swap chain image. Assuming it has `TRANSFER_DST_BIT` of course; if not, then you'll have to render to it.

Assuming you have verified that the surface can be read from at all:

> Call vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer in Command Buffer after the vkCmdDraw, vkCmdEndRenderPass.

Your renderpass will need an execution dependency between writes to the image and the transfer stage.

Comment: I am having issues trying to copy the swap chain images to a buffer. I've had a go setting it up, then followed the error output as best I can and got what feels close. The errors are telling me I'm not allowed to create swap chain images with the `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT` set, however on checking the supportedUsageFlags, they have a value of 31, which means all the first 5 bits are set, including `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT`. Are there any obvious gotchas that I might be missing?